# Foreign keys vanishes after froward engineer on Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

There was a existing MySQL database. I have reversed engineer the db into MySQL Workbench then created some tables and placed some relationship among tables.

At the end I forward engineered the database. Then I observed the db from phpmyadmin, in that db the new tables and other changes have taken places but foreign keys does not seems to be added. What the problem here???? What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys are only supported by very few table engines. What's yours? Set all your tables to InnoDB and your foreign keys will be kept.